# Vue send data to modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have 3 components: TaskList, TaskItem and TaskForm.

The TaskList contains a loop to render all data in TaskItem. Each TaskItem have a edit buttom, that i want to open a TaskForm (modal using bootstrap) with the task data.

TaskForm.vue

```
  <div class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" id="formModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">{{ props.task.name }}</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TaskList.vue

```
  <div class="container">
    <TaskItem
      v-for="task in props.tasks"
      :key="task.uuid"
      :task="task"
    />
  </div>
```

TaskItem.vue

```
  <div class="row align-items-center p-2 border rounded mt-2">
    <div class="col-3">
    {{ props.task.name }}
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="showForm = !showForm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#formModal">
        <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
      </button>
  </div>

  <TaskForm v-if="showForm" :task="props.task"/>
```

But when i do it like this, in every modal, i get the first task name, instead of the selected one.

---

I don't think this is the best way to do what I want to do in the end (edit a list item), but it's the one I came up with. If someone has a better proposal, I will be happy to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the TaskForm component only once, this can be achieved using props and emits like this

```
// for parent component
<template>
<ChildComponent v-for="item in items" key={item.id} :item="item" @edit-item="showEditModal" />
<PopUpComponent v-if="selectedItem !== null" :selected-item="selectedItem" @close="selectedItem = null" />
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
const selectedItem = ref(null);
function showEditModal(item) {
selectedItem.value = item;
}

</script>
```

For child component we need to define an emit named edit-item that will call this function

```
// for child
<template>
..other data
<button @click="editItem">edit</button>
</template>
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(["edit-item"]);

function editItem() {
emit('edit-item', props.item) // this will call the @edit-item in parent and that function will set a selectedItem non-null value which will render the modal
}
</script>
```

Similarly for a close function in modal

```
<template>
...
<button @click="closeModal">close</button>
</template>
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(["close"])
function closeModal() {
emit("close")
}
</script>
```